# how to filter "\" from a json string in javascript

Tags: javascript, c, json, node.js

I receive a json string at my node js server which looks like this:

```
{\"gID\":1,\"sID\":18,\"T\":\"Parking\"}
```

The reason i put in the "\" is because the string is made in C and the \ is used to escape the " which otherwise ends the string.

The code i use now is:

```
 app.get('/add/:jsonString', function(req, res){
        var json = JSON.parse(req.params.jsonString);
 });
```

Is there a way to only delete the \'s in my string?

Comment: `The reason i put in the "\" is because the string is made in C and the \ is used to escape the " which otherwise ends the string.` If this is the case they shouldn't even be in your string.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to remove it, it's not necessary ?

```
var a ="{\"gID\":1,\"sID\":18,\"T\":\"Parking\"}";
console.log(JSON.parse(a));
// give Object { gID: 1, sID: 18, T: "Parking" }
```

EDIT

Use Url encode to pass your get json

```
var str = encodeURIComponent("{\"gID\":1,\"sID\":18,\"T\":\"Parking\"}");
// send your request
request.get({uri:"website/api?data="+str}, ...
```

And in server, decode uri then parse

```
   var string = decodeURIComponent(req.query.data);
  var obj = JSON.parse(string);
```

Comment: you were right, it just filters it out automaticly, I think the problem is in the GET instead of POST 

http://192.168.129.24:3000/add/{/"gID/":1,/"sID/":18,/"T/":/"Parking/"}

I think it sees the / as a new direction...

Comment: See edit, use encodeURIComponent to pass your datas through the GET or POST request, then parse the result of decodeURIComponent

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the "\", try the replace method with a regex pattern:

```
str.replace(/\\/g, "")
```

The g flag is used to replace all occurences of the char "\", while the first "\" is an escape character.

For further details, consult [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you pass JSON into your application using a POST request, as there are plenty of characters that aren't URI-safe.

However, you can use the `unescape` method from the built in `querystring` module.

```
const qs = require('querystring');

app.get('/add/:jsonString', function(req, res){
    const json = JSON.parse(qs.unescape(req.params.jsonString));
});
```